# What is the Mathematica string expression to extract the innertext of an HTML element?

Tags: programming, string-manipulation, html

Consider the following example of text extraction.

```
lst = {
"foo bar <span>feyenoord - ADO</span>",
"foo bar foo <span>Chelsea - Leicester</span>",
"foo bar <span id=\"puin\">feyenoord - ADO Den Haag</span>"};
```

The goal is to take the text in the span element.

```
Map[StringTake[StringCases[#, ">" ~~ __ ~~ "<"], {2, -2}] &, lst]
```

The result is as expected.

```
{
 {"feyenoord - ADO"}, 
 {"Chelsea - Leicester"},
 {"feyenoord - ADO Den Haag"}
}
```

Then I received a somewhat different input text. Note the ">" following "foo" in the third element.

```
lst1 = {
"foo bar <span>feyenoord - ADO</span>",
"foo bar foo <span>Chelsea - Leicester</span>",
"foo> bar <span id=\"puin\">feyenoord - ADO Den Haag</span>"};
```

The goal is still to take the text in the span element.

```
Map[StringTake[StringCases[#, ">" ~~ __ ~~ "<"], {2, -2}] &, lst1]
```

But now, the result is not as expected.

```
{
 {"feyenoord - ADO"}, 
 {"Chelsea - Leicester"}, 
 {" bar <span id=\"puin\">feyenoord - ADO Den Haag"}
}
```

Whatever texts are received, i.e.:

```
 "foo bar <<< foo <span id="id" attr="name">payload</span> foo>span>>>"
```

it is always "payload", the innertext of the span element that needs to be extracted.

I thought about removing id="__"  but other attributes may come in at other times.

So I am basically looking ( and not wanting to reinvent the wheel ) for the **regular expression or Mathematica string expression to extract the innertext of an HTML element** ( span in this case ).

Note that the strings are not valid HTML.

Comment: Using regexp to parse HTML is [not a great idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) in general. If you have a specific pattern, involving `span` or other HTML tags, you can probably write a more specialized regexp for it, but it certainly has to be more specific  than the one you are using. This has nothing to do with Mathematica per se - you would have to construct it for whatever language you'd use for extraction. Or you could use one of the proper HTML parsers, and then postprocess the result symbolically.

Comment: Actually I am in the post-post-processing, and it is not HTML.

Comment: Is this something useful: `StringCases["foo> bar <span id=\"puin\">feyenoord - ADO Den Haag</span>", 
 "<span" ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ ">" ~~ x : Shortest[__] ~~ "</span" :> x]` ?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The Mathematica Tutorial for Advanced String Patterns says: "String patterns are useful for taking raw HTML and extracting information from it"

Comment: String patterns are surely useful for this, I don't dispute that. They just stop working well when the complexity of a piece you want to parse increases. In your particular case, something like what @FredSimons suggested should work pretty well, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I am working with fairly simple HTML "snippets".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jSoupLink](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink) can be used if the markup looks like HTML. So even though you contend that your input is not HTML, the following still works:

```
<< jSoupLink`
getSpan[str_] := First[ImportString[str, "HTMLDOM"]["Select", "span"]]["OwnText"]

getSpan["foo bar <span id=\"puin\">feyenoord - ADO Den Haag</span>"]
```

> `"feyenoord - ADO Den Haag"`

```
getSpan["foo> bar <span id=\"puin\">feyenoord - ADO Den Haag</span>"]
```

> `"feyenoord - ADO Den Haag"`

```
getSpan["foo bar <<< foo <span id=\"id\" attr=\"name\">payload</span> foo>span>>>"]
```

> `"payload"`

Comment: I am using a stack of Conductor / Selenium / WebDriver / PhantomJS at the moment to query websites using CSS selectors. - I have looked at jSoup in the design phase but I'll definitely have another look. - Your reply is highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @C.E. After PacletInstalling the latest build, the << doesn't work for me...

Comment: @M.R. Thank you for telling me, I will look into it when I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

lst = {"foo bar <span>feyenoord - ADO</span>", 
   "foo bar foo <span>Chelsea - Leicester</span>", 

   "foo bar <span id=\"puin\">feyenoord - ADO Den Haag</span>"};

h1 = "foo bar <<< foo <span id=\"id\" attr=\"name\">payload</span>foo>span>>>"
```

---

Start with the simpler case:

```
StringCases[#, "<span>" ~~ s : __ ~~ "</span>" -> s] & /@ lst
```

> {{"feyenoord - ADO"}, {"Chelsea - Leicester"}, {}}

Let's keep building the pattern up to handle the missed case where the span tag has more attributes.

```
StringCases[#, 
   "<span" ~~ ___ ~~ ">" ~~ s : ___ ~~ "</span>" -> s] & /@ lst
```

> {{"feyenoord - ADO"}, {"Chelsea - Leicester"}, {"feyenoord - ADO Den 
> Haag"}}

For the other example, the same solution extracts innertext:

```
StringCases[#, 
   "<span" ~~ ___ ~~ ">" ~~ s : ___ ~~ "</span>" -> s] &@h1
```

> {"payload"}

---

**EDIT-1**

With a text file containing many `span` tags, the above requires a tweak using `Shortest`, otherwise the last `span` block is grabbed. For example:

```
h2 = "foo bar <span>first inner - ABC</span>foo bar foo <span>Second \
one</span>foo bar <span id=\"ghi\">Bit Next one</span>foo bar \
<span>Not the Last one</span>foo bar <<< foo <span id=\"id\" \
attr=\"name\">payload</span> foo>span>>>"


StringCases[#,  
   "<span" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ ">" ~~ s : Shortest[___] ~~ 
     "</span>" :> s] &@h2
```

{"first inner - ABC", "Second one", "Bit Next one", "Not the Last 
one", "payload"}